# How to convert a javascript String to an Object

Tags: javascript, variables, object, type-conversion

I am getting the variable from a json file that is

```
var node = data.nodes;
```

`alert(node);` returns the following

```
[{"name" : "30","group": 0} , {"name" : "40","group": 0} ]
```

which is not an Object

If I assign this value directly to a variable then it is counted as object as you can see below.

```
var node = [{"name" : "30","group": 0} , {"name" : "40","group": 0} ]
```

Why is the value not an Object in the first place?
What can I do to convert the variable to an Object?

any help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is :) @Petrichor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method to turn the string into an object:

```
var node = JSON.parse(data.nodes);
```

Note that some older browsers (e.g. IE 7) doesn't support the `JSON` object. You can read more about that on the documentation page that I linked to if you need to support older versions.

Answer (score 3):

Try  this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var node = data.nodes //[{"name" : "30","group": 0} , {"name" : "40","group": 0} ]
var data = JSON.parse(node);
console.log(data); //{name: "30", group: 0}, {name: "40", group: 0}
console.log(data[0]); //{name: "30", group: 0}
</script>
```